# Missing space with pdfmanagement and lualatex

Tags: luatex, tagpdf

I'm observing missing spaces in certain situations when using the `pdfmanagement-testphase` package and LuaLatex, and I am not sure if this is intended.

Here's a small example that demonstrates the issue:

```
\DocumentMetadata{
    testphase=phase-I
}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\{a\} \text{test}$
$\{a\} \text{ test}$
$\{a\}\ \text{test}$

\end{document}
```

When processing the example with LuaLatex I get the following result:

[image: Result with pdfmanagement and LuaLatex]
(no space after the second pair of braces)

This also happens when using `testphase=phase-II`. However, when I process the same example either with pdfLatex or without the
`DocumentMetadata` command, I get what I would expect:

[image: Result without pdfmanagement or LuaLatex]
(a space after the second pair of braces)

Is this intended behavior, or might this be a bug? Is there a way to keep this space when using `pdfmanagement-testphase` and luaLatex?

For additional information, the output of luaLatex:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2023-02-07>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latex-lab/documentmetadata-suppor
t.ltx
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/pdfmanage
ment-testphase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tagpdf/tagpdf-base.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/pdfmanage
ment-testphase.ltx
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3bitset/l3bitset.
sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/l3backend
-testphase-luatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/l3ref-tmp
.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latex-lab/phase-I-latex-lab-testp
hase.ltx (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tagpdf/tagpdf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tagpdf/tagpdf-luatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tagpdf/tagpdf-mc-code-lua.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/pdfmanage
ment-firstaid.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/output-pa
tches-tmp-ltx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
Patching header in \@outputpage
Patching footer in \@outputpage
Patching \@makecol for tagging
Patching \@makecol for tagging
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (./test.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1{/usr/local/tex
live/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux))
 505 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 3 glyph, 10 attribute, 51 glue_spe
c, 8 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:62,3:24,4:6,5:22,6:2,7:94,8:8,9:38
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.
otf></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.p
fb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pf
b>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 30029 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Hm, the interwordspace code seems to eat the space, please open a bug at the issue tracker of tagpdf, I will look later.

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really was a bug in the tagpdf package (https://github.com/u-fischer/tagpdf/issues/66). The bug was fixed in version 0.98d of tagpdf, released 2023-02-15. The example in the question now produces the expected result.